# c++ vector reverse algorithm

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a simple program which basically reverse the sequence of the vector. In other words after the program is ran, `x[0]` should be equal to `5`. The output which I am currently getting is `5234`. The `1` goes missing somewhere. I did include the `<vector>` header. Thanks in advance.

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> x(5);
    x[0] = 1;
    x[1] = 2;
    x[2] = 3;
    x[3] = 4;
    x[4] = 5;
    for(int z = 0; z < x.size()-1; z++)
    {
        int temp = x[x.size() - (1+z)];
        x[x.size() - (1+z)] = x[z];
        x[z] = temp;
    }
    for(int s = 0; s < x.size() - 1; s++)
    {
        cout << x[s] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Viral while adding the homework tag, did you notice the description of the homework tag? "This tag is OBSOLETE and is in the process of being removed. Please do NOT add this tag to questions. But don't remove it without looking at the question to see if it needs cleanup."

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a step back a minute. What do you think this will do if I just put in swap (pseudo code)

```
for( elt1 = begin, elt2 = end-1; elt1 != end; ++elt1, --elt2 )
{
    iter_swap( elt1, elt2 );
}
```

This will not reverse your collection. Or rather it will, but will then reverse it back again leaving you where you started. Say your collection has 4 elements:

```
swap( 0, 3 )
swap( 1, 2 )
swap( 2, 1 )
swap( 3, 0 )
```

So your terminating condition is wrong, you should only swap halfway...

Answer (score 3):

Your loops are 1 element short. They should be

```
for(int z = 0; z < x.size(); ++z)
```

(dtto for `s`).

Comment: I changed the for loop as you said and that fixed the "one missing digit" problem, however I still get the output as 1/2/3/4/5 and not as 5/4/3/2/1.

Comment: As CashCow pointed out, the first loop should actually terminate at `x.size() / 2`.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than writing the code to reverse the vector you should use the `std::reverse`algorithm?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/

Why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of people have pointed out how to make your code work. I'll point out how to avoid the problem in the future: don't write the code (yourself):

```
std::vector<int> x(5);

std::iota(x.begin(), x.end(), 1);

std::reverse(x.begin(), x.end());

std::copy(x.begin(), x.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Reversing just before copying like this is common enough that the standard has an algorithm to combine the two though:

```
std::vector<int> x(5);   
std::iota(x.begin(), x.end(), 1);

std::reverse_copy(x.begin(), x.end(),
                  std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Depending on the situation, it may be easier to user reverse iterators instead of reverse_copy:

```
std::vector<int> x(5);   
std::iota(x.begin(), x.end(), 1);

std::copy(x.rbegin(), x.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Note that in the latter two cases, what we're doing is subtly different though -- we're not reversing the data in the vector, then printing out the vector from beginning to end. Rather, we're just printing out the vector in reverse order, roughly equivalent to:

```
for (int i=x.size(); i>0; i--)
    std::cout << x[i-1] << "\n";
```

One final detail: I'd advise against using `std::endl`. I know a lot of books (and teachers, instructors, professors, etc.) use it as a replacement for "\n", but it's really not. In addition to writing a new-line, it flushes the stream. You *almost* never want that; on the rare occasion that you do, you should use `std::flush` instead to make it clear that you really want it. If you want a newline, just write a newline.

Answer (score 0):

You're swapping the elements twice. Here's a simple way to do it:

```
vector<int> x(5);
x[0] = 1;
x[1] = 2;
x[2] = 3;
x[3] = 4;
x[4] = 5;

int mid = x.size() / 2;
int last = x.size() - 1;

for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
  int tmp = x[i];
  x[i] = last - i;
  x[last - i] = tmp;
}

for (int s = 0; s < x.size(); s++)
  cout << x[s] << endl;
```